# tmux in putty: use ctrl-arrow to switch window

Tags: putty, tmux

I found several questions about this, but I didn't find a working answer.

I'm using putty (0.63) to login to my ubuntu 14.04 vps.
In tmux I would like to use ctrl-left and ctrl-right to switch tmux windows.

Here are the tmux settings I'm using:

```
bind -n C-Right next-window
bind -n C-Left previous-window
set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-265color"
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
```

The terminal type string in putty is set to "xterm-256color"

When I login to the vps without starting tmux I have these keycodes:

```
left: ^[[D
right: ^[[C
ctrl-left: ^[OD
ctrl-right: ^[OC
```

After starting tmux ctrl-left has the same code as left and ctrl-right has the same code as right.

I tried different settings in putty, but I always get the same codes.

Do I need to make changes in terminfo/inputrc/...? How do I do that?

Can I solve this with "set -g terminal-overrides" in tmux ?
Where can I find a list of codes or a detailed explanation?

Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I just had to add this to .tmux.conf:

```
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
```

I tried that before, but there already was a different "set -g terminal-overrides" in the config with other settings. After removing that everything worked.

I found the solution here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129912

**Update**: Here my complete tmux config after some more changes:

```
bind -n C-Right next-window
bind -n C-Left previous-window
set-option -g default-terminal "screen"
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@:XT:Ms=\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\007:Cc=\E]12;%p1%s\007:Cr=\E]112\007:Cs=\E[%p1%d q:Csr=\E[2 q,screen*:XT,*256col*:colors=256"
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
set-option -g assume-paste-time 1
set-option -g base-index 0
set-option -g bell-action any
set-option -g bell-on-alert off
set-option -g default-command ""
set-option -g default-path ""
set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"
set-option -g destroy-unattached off
set-option -g detach-on-destroy on
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour red
set-option -g display-panes-colour blue
set-option -g display-panes-time 1000
set-option -g display-time 750
set-option -g history-limit 2000
set-option -g lock-after-time 0
set-option -g lock-command "lock -np"
set-option -g lock-server on
set-option -g message-attr none
set-option -g message-bg colour16
set-option -g message-command-attr none
set-option -g message-command-bg colour16
set-option -g message-command-fg colour253
set-option -g message-fg colour253
set-option -g message-limit 20
set-option -g mouse-resize-pane off
set-option -g mouse-select-pane off
set-option -g mouse-select-window off
set-option -g mouse-utf8 on
set-option -g pane-active-border-bg default
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg colour144
set-option -g pane-border-bg default
set-option -g pane-border-fg colour16
set-option -g prefix C-b
set-option -g renumber-windows off
set-option -g repeat-time 500
set-option -g set-remain-on-exit off
set-option -g set-titles off
set-option -g set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T""
set-option -g status on
set-option -g status-attr none
set-option -g status-bg colour67
set-option -g status-fg black
set-option -g status-interval 15
set-option -g status-justify left
set-option -g status-keys emacs
set-option -g status-left "#[fg=colour232,bg=colour144] #S #[fg=colour144,bg=colour67,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]"
set-option -g status-left-attr none
set-option -g status-left-bg default
set-option -g status-left-fg default
set-option -g status-left-length 100
set-option -g status-position bottom
set-option -g status-right "#[fg=colour16,bg=colour67,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=colour253,bg=colour16] %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M #[fg=colour144,bg=colour16,nobold,nounderscore,noitalics]#[fg=colour232,bg=colour144] #h "
set-option -g status-right-attr none
set-option -g status-right-bg default
set-option -g status-right-fg default
set-option -g status-right-length 100
set-option -g status-utf8 on
set-option -g update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
set-option -g visual-activity off
set-option -g visual-bell off
set-option -g visual-content off
set-option -g visual-silence off
set-option -g word-separators " -_@"
```